# take an array and return its items, line by line

Tags: node.js

im trying to take an array and make it line by line, and write it in a new text file using writefilesync, for example: const arr = [1,2,3], in the text file it should show:

a
b
c

```
const fs = require ('fs');
const tip = [1,2,3]
for (let i =0; i < tip.length; i ++) {
    tip[i] = tip[i] + "<br / >";
    return tip;
}

let textFile = fs.writeFileSync ('text.txt', tip, 'utf8');
```

the result in the text file should be line by line

1
2
3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, try with this one:

```
const fs = require ('fs');
const tip = [1,2,3];
const result = tip.join('\n');

let textFile = fs.writeFileSync ('text.txt', result, 'utf8');
```

Here, you are creating a string from the array by joining each element using a `\n` sign, which represents a newline.

The error in your code was that you were adding `<br />` tag to break the lines, which is an HTML tag and it would work only in the browser but not in a regular file.

---

Using for-loop, the above would look like this:

```
const fs = require ('fs');
const tip = [1,2,3];
let result = '';

for (let i = 0; i < tip.length; i++) {
    result += tip[i] + '\n';
}

let textFile = fs.writeFileSync ('text.txt', result, 'utf8');
```

Comment: hi, thinks for the answer, but i still have one question. what if i have to use a for loop? is there any way to do that?

Comment: @AtypicalEEL use `\n` - this is a newline character. While `<br / >` is the HTML markup for a newline.